# Inner class as hibernate component

Tags: java, hibernate, inner-classes

Basically, **is that possible**?

Docs say

> A component is a contained object that is persisted as a value type and not an entity reference.
>
> Like value types, components do not support shared references. In other words, two persons could have the same name, but the two person objects would contain two independent name objects that were only "the same" by value.
>
> The main distinguishing characteristic of a value type is the fact that they do not define their own lifecycle. We say that they are "owned" by something else (specifically an entity, as we will see later) which defines their lifecycle.

Non-static inner class can fit perfectly into this, but i've never seen examples in practice. Is there any limitation of using inner classes as components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research i discovered that answer is **no, it's not possible**

And the reason is quite simple and (in my understanding) is connected only with hibernate tool itself, not with any architectural issues. Hibernate requires a component class to have default no-arg constructor and fails to instantiate inner class (though it accepts mapping successfully). I hope this feature will be supported in future releases of Hibernate.

Answer (score 5):

The JPA specification says:

> Embeddable classes must adhere to the requirements specified in Section 2.1 for entities with the excep- tion that embeddable classes are not annotated as Entity.

and section 2.1 says:

> The entity class must be a top-level class.

Comment: it seems taht hibernate ignores JPA recommendations about embeddables

Answer (score 0):

You must mark the inner component class as `static`.

Comment: I tried with static inner class (component/embedded) and don't work